# Cannot open Visio document with Python

Tags: python, visio, pywin32, win32com

I am attempting to do some automation in Visio using Python.  I am able to open the Visio application and create a new document, but cannot open an existing document.  Here is the code that I am trying.

```
  import win32com.client

  visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")  # this works
  doc = visio.Documents.Open("C:\Users\username\test.vsd") # nope
```

The error I get back is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in OpenEx
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Visio', u'\n\nFile not found.', None, 0, -2032465466), None)
```

I have tried using visio.Documents.OpenEx as well and get the same answer.  Any thoughts?

Comment: error says `File not found`

Comment: can you try `doc = visio.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\username\test.vsd")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that this might work -

```
doc = visio.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\username\\test.vsd")
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't realize I had to escape the backslashes.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I thought Visio itself is not installed in the machine... but if it worked then +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forward slashes you can use backward ones

```
doc = visio.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\username\test.vsd")
```

or

```
doc = visio.Documents.Open("C:/Users/username/test.vsd")
```